# Linq2Entities, many to many and dynamic where clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, lambda

I'm fairly new to Linq and struggling using dynamic where over a many to many relationship.

Database tables are like so:

Products <-> Products_SubCategories <-> SubCategories

with `Products_SubCategories` being a link table.

My full linq statement is

```
 db.Products.Where("it.SubCategories.SubCategoryID = 2")
                   .Include("SubCategories")
                   .OrderBy(searchOrderBy)
                   .Skip(currentPage * pageSize)
                   .Take(pageSize)
                   .ToList()
                   .ForEach(p => AddResultItem(items, p));
```

So ignoring everything bar the `Where()` I'm just trying to pull out all products which are linked to sub category ID 2, this fails with

> To extract properties out of collections, you must use a sub-query to iterate over the collection., near multipart identifier, line 8, column 1.

I think using the SQL-esque syntax I can do a subquery as per [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/b3e31b7c-173a-4b19-ba84-f9e75bce2be8/). However I'm not sure how to do that in the lambda / chaining syntax.

This is the start of a search function and I would like to build up the where string dynamically, as I have with the `searchOrderBy` string to avoid a large `SELECT CASE`. Products is linked to another table via a link table that I will need to include once I understand how to do this example.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
db.Products.Where("it.SubCategories.SubCategoryID = 2")
```

`SubCategories` is a list. It does not have a property called `SubCategoryID`. Rather, it contains a group of entities which each have a property called `SubCategoryID`. That's a critical distinction.

When you run into a situation where you don't know how to proceed in there are multiple problems, it is good to break the problem down into several, smaller problems.

Let's start by removing the dynamic query. It will be easier to solve the problem with a non-dynamic query. Once you've done that, you can go back and make it dynamic again.

So start by using the non-dynamic syntax. Type something like this in Visual Studio, and see what IntelliSense does for you:

```
db.Products.Where(p => p.SubCategories.
```

You will quickly see that there is no `SubCategoryID` property. Instead, you will see a bunch of LINQ API methods for working with lists. If you know LINQ well, you will recognize that the `Any()` method is what you want here:

```
db.Products.Where(p => p.SubCategories.Any(sc => sc.SubCategoryID == 2))
```

Go ahead and run that query. Does it work? If so, you can move ahead to making it dynamic. I'm no ESQL expert, but I'd start with something along the lines of:

```
db.Products.Where("EXISTS(SELECT SC FROM it.SubCategories AS SC WHERE SC.SubCategoryID = 2");
```

As an aside, I use MS Dynamic Query ("Dynamic LINQ") for this sort of thing rather than Query Builder, as it's more testable.

Comment: Thanks Craig, clear consisce and good working. Id backed myself into a bit of a corner! Ive changed the implemention quite a lot as ive incorporated FT search via a SP but this has helped my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
db.Products.Where("SubCategories.Any(SubCategoryID = 2)")
```